# How to assign value to a variable from nested function

Tags: python, python-3.x

try to understand how to assign value to a variable from nested function. but it does not work. is it because when I use `a = b`, it consider a is local variable for nested function? then how can I assign value to the a variable from func?

```py
def func():
    a = 0
    def nested(b):
        global a
        a = b
    nested(3)
    return a
print(func())
```

Comment: ideally, return from the nested function, and assign. dont mess with scopes if you dont have to.

Comment: Use `nonlocal` instead of `global`, that being said I agree with @ParitoshSingh that you should return not assign the value unless you are working with something like a decorator.

Answer (score 5):

Use `nonlocal` to access data in the enclosing scope:

```
def func():
    a = 0
    def nested(b):
        nonlocal a
        a = b
    nested(3)
    return a
print(func()) # => 3
```

Having said this, using the `global` and `nonlocal` keywords break encapsulation and is a design antipattern that is nearly always avoidable using parameters and return statements.

Comment: I was stuck on thinking of why global was wrong and completely blanked on swapping it to nonlocal. Better answer for sure.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your solution isn't working is that you're assigning your value to `a` in the global scope. If you would `print(a)` outside your outer function (and thus in the global scope) you would get the value `3`.

To get your desired effect you would use `nonlocal` instead of `global` like this:

```
def func():
    a = 0
    def nested(b):
        nonlocal a
        a = b
    nested(3)
    return a
```

However a more appropriate solution would be to not mess with the scope and return the desired value from the nested function instead, and then assign it.